# Where is the Create New Connection button in the Connections panel in IIS 8?

Tags: iis, windows-8

[image: IIS 8 connections panel]

I need to connect to a Windows server through IIS 8 to configure a website, but I can't create a new connection in my manager.

[The online documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635849.aspx) tells about a set of buttons I am supposed to have in the highlighted area of the screenshot above, but apparently these are absent on my end.

From the online documentation:

> The Connections toolbar contains the following buttons that let you
>   interact with the tree:
>
> **Create New Connection**: starts the connection
>   wizard to connect to a web server, a site, or an application.
>
> **Save Current Connections**: saves the connection information for the
>   current list of connections in the tree.
>
> **Up**: goes up one level in the hierarchy.
>
> **Delete Connection**: removes the selected connection in the tree. If you
>   click this button when you are on a node other than the connection
>   node, such as a physical folder, the parent connection is removed from
>   the list.

The only button available is the **Up** button, as per screenshot.

How do I create a new connection in my manager? Did I miss installing a certain package with the Web Platform Installer, or do I have to enable something in the Windows features?

Comment: Is everything installed properly under the server role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install this:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=&appid=RemoteManager%3bRemoteManager

Add a "Create New Connection" button to IIS manager.

Comment: That link is broken. There is not "remote" on that page.
What is the official name for that? perhaps IIS Manager for Remote Administration 1.2?  http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager

Answer (score 8):

Link in the accepted answer is broken.

What it seems to refer to is:

[IIS Manager for Remote Administration](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager) which fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you! I was on the verge of re-installing Windows (again)... Issue still present on Windows 11, BTW